# How to enable tenant restriction in a correct way

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, passport-azure-ad

How can I restrict user sign-in for a particular domain?

During the registration process, you can set your application as a `single-tenant` and as I understood according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-and-multi-tenant-apps) it uses in the case of `if your target audience is internal to your organization.`. But there is not an option to specify a domain for tenancy restriction.

But I've found that [you can restrict users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/tenant-restrictions) by specifying the white list of tenants in the HTTP header `Restrict-Access-To-Tenants` using a proxy server.

And I can't understand what the `single-tenant` option is influence on?
And is there any functionality provided by `passport-azure-ad` for tenancy restriction?

Thanks.

Comment: The single-tenant application only allows users of this tenant to log in to the application, and the multi-tenant application allows users of other tenants (other domains) to log in.

Comment: I can't get it. Because I've logged in through my `@gmail.com` account that is linked to GitHub.

Comment: Is this account in your tenant?

Comment: Is your application a single-tenant application or a multi-tenant application?

Comment: my application is a `single-tenant` and `publisher domain` is `yaroslavtereshchukgmail.onmicrosoft.com`

Comment: Well,, do you mean that your account is not in your domain, but it can log in to your application?

Comment: yes, I want to understand why is that happening and I want to understand the correct way of managing tenant restrictions for signing-in

Comment: @ЯрославТерещук Are you using ROPC flow to acquire token successfully with your gmail.com account?That's weird.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `enterprise application->User assignment required?` to Yes on the Properties tab.

Then you go to `Users and groups` tab and add the users and groups that you want to allow to access it (internals and partners).

By default, without this setting all internal and partner users can sign in.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand the difference between [single-tenant applications and multi-tenant applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-and-multi-tenant-apps#who-can-sign-in-to-your-app):

> **Single-tenant** apps are only available in the tenant they were registered in, also known as their home tenant.
>
> **Multi-tenant** apps are available to users in both their home tenant and other tenants.

If your application is a single-tenant application, users of other tenants cannot log in. Of course, you can also [invite other users to join your tenant as a guest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal), and the guest user can also log in to your application.

If you want to restrict users in this tenant from logging in to the application, you can:[Restrict your Azure AD app to a set of users in an Azure AD tenant.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-restrict-your-app-to-a-set-of-users)

Comment: My application is a single-tenant and the publisher domain is `yaroslavtereshchukgmail.onmicrosoft.com`. But why then I was able to log in via my `@gmail.com` linked to GitHub?

Comment: and if I make restrictions for a set of users, I will need to add each user to log in manually. That's not what I'm looking for, I want to restrict users for a particular domain.

Comment: How did you log in? Please provide a URL.

Comment: @ЯрославТерещук       You need to log in with `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}` instead of `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{common}`

Comment: I'm logging-in using `passport-azure-ad` with config `identityMetadata:
      'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration',`